# Laravel DebugBar Conflict with Tablesorter?

Tags: jquery, laravel, tablesorter

I've been using [Mottie's excellent tablesorter](https://github.com/Mottie/tablesorter) for a long time.  Working great.  I've just added [Barryvdh's laravel-debugbar](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-debugbar), and found that package fantastic as well.

I am finding a conflict on some pages however.  The tablesorter pagination mechanism correctly prints out the number of pages and the arrows to move to the next set.  Then, a microsecond later, the page data vanishes, and just shows 0 entries in the row count, and no way to move to the next page (as TS thinks there are 0 rows and thus greys-out the arrows).

I note that debugbar loads its own JS file LAST (IE After TS).  I fully realize this could be a million things - I have been searching for some kind of conflicted JS var name for hours.

I was just wondering if anyone else had had this issue, and if so, was there a solution.  I can live with it as it is only dev, but I'd like to know what the conflict is. Both are latest versions, and Laravel 5.4

Comment: Do you see any errors in the console? Have you tried setting tablesorter's `debug` option to `true` and looking in the console for any issues?

Comment: Hi @Mottie.  Thank you as always for your help and TS.  I did indeed set TS debug to true.  No errors, and no errors in console.  I *really* don't think this is a TS error or issue.  I think it is something that Debugbar is doing to reset or overlay the screen, which wipes out the count.   No idea what or where - and may never know.  I can't even figure out why it only is repeatable on some pages, as I can't see any differences in JS library pulls.  Thanks again.